# Are there any other ways but usercontrols for multiple windows inside a mainwindow?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a window with a menu on the left side (in the form of Buttons). The right side of the window changes according to what was clicked on the left side.

Thus so to say I have 4 different "subwindows" that have the same place on the "main window".

After doing some Research I used usercontrols to achieve this behaviour. Thus the usercontrols take the place of the subwindows and are visible depending on which button was clicked in the mainwindows.

The usercontrols have different elements (Buttons, textboxes, ...) inside and also have different code on how to autofill the elements, ... .

So far this construct works, but after a few comments in another question of mine I'm wondering:

Are there any other ways but usercontrols to easily achieve this behavior?

Comment: You could use a Tab control but even then loading UCs into the pages wo7uld be recommended.. - What is wrong with using UCs? (MDI is so old-fashioned I would not even consider it)

Comment: I think the easiest way is showing and hiding panels as you need.

Comment: UCs are usually good enough, question could use more details, like code/exact problems you encoutered.

Comment: @user6144226  there are no Errors, I was just curious if there is currently a different way how things can / are done after a few comments in another questin of mine (where I got asked why I use UC's if they are only used in a single form and not multiple ones).

Comment: @TaW There is nothing wrong with UCs, I just wondered / got curious (after a few comments in another question of mine) if there are currently other methods and if UCs are currenlty still "up to date" or already something quite old and outdated. Thus my question what other methods / variants exist currently.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to create an MDI (Multiple Document Interface) application.

This page talks you through the initial steps to doing so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms